# How to get version number from string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a variable having following format
`bundle="chn-pro-X.Y-Z.el8.x86_64"`

X,Y,Z are numbers having any number of digits
**Ex:**

```
1.0-2  # X=1 Y=0 Z=2
12.45-9874 # X=12 Y=45 Z=9874
```

How can I grab `X.Y` and store it in another variable?

**EDIT:**

I wasn't right with my wording, but
I want to store `X.Y` into new variable not individual `X` & `Y`'s
I'm looking to finally have a variable `version` which has `X.Y` grabbed from `bundle`:
`version="X.Y"`

Comment: please update the question with samples of complete strings; are all strings of the format stuff`<hyphen>`stuff`<hyphen>`X.Y`<hyphen>`morestuff (ie, the version string is ***always*** between the 2nd and 3rd hyphen? if not, then include enough sample strings to represent the different formats you need to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
bundle="chn-pro-12.45-9874.el8.x86_64"
echo "$bundle" | awk -F "[.-]" '{print $3,$4,$5}'
12 45 9874
```

Now if you want to assign to `x, y, z` use `read` and process substitution:

```
read -r x y z < <(echo "$bundle" | awk -F "[.-]" '{print $3,$4,$5}')

echo "x=$x, y=$y, z=$z"
x=12, y=45, z=9874
```

---

If you just want the value of `X.Y` as a single value this is still great use for awk:

```
bundle="chn-pro-12.45-9874.el8.x86_64"
echo "$bundle" | awk -F "[-]" '{print $3}'
12.45
```

And if you then want to put that into a variable:

```
x_y=$(echo "$bundle" | awk -F "[-]" '{print $3}')
echo "x_y=$x_y"
x_y=12.45
```

Or you can use `cut` in this case to get the third field:

```
echo "$bundle" | cut -d- -f3
12.45
```

Comment: Added EDIT for what I was looking for...

Comment: Edited to what I *think* you want.

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```
$ bundle="chn-pro-1.0-2.el8.x86_64"
$ X="$(echo "$bundle" | cut -d . -f1 | cut -d- -f3)"
$ Y="$(echo "$bundle" | cut -d . -f2 | cut -d- -f1)"
$ Z="$(echo "$bundle" | cut -d . -f2 | cut -d- -f2)"
$ echo "$X"
1
$ echo "$Y"
0
$ echo "$Z"
2
```

You can merge `X` and `Y` into a single variable:

```
$ XY="$X.$Y"
$ echo $XY
1.0
```

Comment: I'm looking to store X.Y into single variable not individual X&Y's

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to separate numbers:

```
numbers=$(echo $bundle | grep -Eo '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)' | sed 's/\./\t/g;s/\-/\t/g')
```

Then assign them to variables with using awk or tr or cut, whatever you want:

```
X=$(echo $numbers| awk '{print $1}')
Y=$(echo $numbers| awk '{print $2}')
Z=$(echo $numbers| awk '{print $3}')
```

**EDIT**

For storing x.y into single version variable you can simply ignore pervios commands:

```
version=$(echo $bundle | grep -Eo '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)' | grep -Eo '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
$ bundle="chn-pro-12.45-9874.el8.x86_64"
```

using GNU or BSD sed for `-E`:

```
$ foo=$(echo "$bundle" | sed -E 's/.*-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-[0-9].*/\1/')
$ echo "$foo"
12.45
```

or with any sed:

```
$ foo=$(echo "$bundle" | sed 's/.*-\([0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\)-[0-9].*/\1/')
$ echo "$foo"
12.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- the input string will always contain (at least) 3 hyphens
- the desired `version` string will always reside between the 2nd and 3rd hyphens of the input string
- we need to maintain the input string (ie, don't clobber/overwrite the variable containing the input string)

We can eliminate the subprocess calls (necessary for `echo/sed/grep/awk/sed`) by using some [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ bundle="chn-pro-X.Y-Z.el8.x86_64"

$ temp="${bundle#*-}"                   # strip off 1st hyphen delimited string
$ echo "${temp}"
pro-X.Y-Z.el8.x86_64

$ temp="${temp#*-}"                     # strip off 2nd hyphen delimited string
$ echo "${temp}"
X.Y-Z.el8.x86_64

$ version="${temp%%-*}"                 # save 3rd hyphen delimited string (aka our version)
$ echo "${version}"
X.Y
```

**NOTE:** We can eliminate the `temp` variable by replacing all occurrences of `temp` with `version` with the understanding `version`  does not contain what we want until after the 3rd parameter expansion has occurred, eg:

```
$ bundle="chn-pro-X.Y-Z.el8.x86_64"
$ version="${bundle#*-}"
$ version="${version#*-}"
$ version="${version%%-*}"
$ echo "${version}"
X.Y
```